# Parameters for fitted distribution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, pymc3

When searching for the best-fit distribution for my dataset, the result was the Exponentially Modified Normal distribution with the following parameters:

```
K=10.84, loc=154.35, scale=73.82
```

Scipy gives us a way to analyze the mean of the distribution by:

```
  fitted_mean =  scipy.stats.exponnorm.stats(K=10.84, loc=154.35, scale=73.82, moments='mean')
```

The resulting fitted_mean=984, which is the same mean as my dataset. However, I'm not sure what this is telling me. I thought the loc=154.35 is the mean of the distribution.

**What are these two means? If I fitted the data with the best distribution, isn't the fitted_mean (154.35) the new and only mean?**

Comment: FYI: I get `fitted_mean` to be `954.5587999999999`, not `984`.  Is your value a typo?

Comment: Yes, sorry it was just a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the exponentially modified normal distribution, the location parameter is *not* the same as the mean.  This is true for many distributions.

Take a look at the [wikipedia page for the exponentially modified Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentially_modified_Gaussian_distribution).  This is the same distribution as `scipy.stats.exponnorm`, but with a different parameterization.  The mapping of the parameters between the wikipedia version and scipy is:

```
μ = loc
σ = scale
λ = 1/(K*scale)
```

The wikipedia page says the mean of the distribution is μ + 1/λ, which, in terms of the scipy parameters, is `loc + K*scale`.

When you fit the distribution to your data, you found

```
loc = 154.35
scale = 73.82 
K = 10.84
```

The formula for the mean from the wikipedia page gives

```
loc + K*scale = 954.5587999999999
```

Here is the calculation using `exponnorm`:

```
In [16]: fitted_mean = scipy.stats.exponnorm.stats(K=10.84, loc=154.35, scale=73.82, moments='mean')

In [17]: fitted_mean
Out[17]: array(954.5587999999999)
```

which matches the result from the wikipedia formula.

(You reported `fitted_mean = 984`, but I assume that was a typographical error.)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying @Warren Weckesser . Yes. it was a typo. So the loc parameter in the exponnonm distribution is just a location parameter, not the mean? But in other distributions like the normal distribution it is the mean?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Another example is the [Gumbel distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution): μ is the location parameter, but the mean is μ + βγ, where β is the scale parameter and γ is Euler-Mascheroni constant.